# Envio de e-mails de aniversário com base em consulta MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, email, envio-de-email, task

Tenho que criar uma função (task) no servidor do meu site que envie um e-mail de aniversário, contendo um código HTML, para e-mails de aniversariantes.

Detalhe: esses aniversariantes estão cadastrados em uma tabela MySQL que contém nome, e-mail e data de nascimento. Portanto, se houver nessa tabela nomes cujo dia e mês sejam iguais a da data de hoje, manda o e-mail de aniversário pra esses nomes.

Portanto, a task se trataria de integrar com o MySQL e fazer o envio desses e-mails dependendo do resultado da consulta (dia e mês iguais à data atual, manda e-mail. Senão, não manda).

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Por enquanto, nada. Sei que tem empresas que oferecem softwares mais dedicados a esse tipo de coisa. Mas se por task scheduler desse pra fazer isso... se tiver que criar algum código em PHP e Javascript, não é o problema. O problema seria como ativar esse envio automático do e-mail, considerando sempre que tem de ser quando o aniversário do dono do e-mail é hoje.

Comment: Você vai incorporar isso no seu site? De que forma pensa em fazer?

Comment: Eu pensei em incorporar no site. Mas também pensei se a solução mais adequada não é fazer um arquivo BAT que fique salvo no servidor e que faça essa consulta SQL pra depois enviar os e-mails.

Comment: Acho que você pode processar na index... são muitos registros?

Comment: Feito o processamento do script pelo include no index, fazemos o envio de acordo com o select, e creio para otimizar bem, você pode até fazer o envio em smtp, que é mais dificil de ser considerado como spam, claro que há outras regras auxiliares...

Comment: O número de registros depende muito de quantos aniversariantes tem num certo dia. Às vezes pode ter vários, às vezes poucos, às vezes um só, às vezes nenhum. Tu tem alguma ideia de código? @AndréBaill

Comment: Não, ai teríamos que elaborar... se você iniciar o código e os testes, posso te ajudar até chegarmos a uma solução.

Comment: A melhor opção é usar CronJob, você cria um no seu servidor para sempre executar uma url para o arquivo php responsavel pelo disparo. Manda fazer isso uma vez por dia, e fim!

Fica automático e só vai precisar de PHP.

O CRONJOB da pra fazer pelo CPANEL, é bem simples!

Answer (score 1):

Gente, descobri a solução fazendo um task e criando uma página no meu servidor.

Quando acessada a página, o e-mail é enviado. E o task pra ele abrir o browser nessa página acontecerá sempre às 9h. Assim fica automatizada a página!

Obrigado pelas respostas de vocês mesmo assim.

Comment: Edite sua resposta com a solução encontrada.